# Customizing app.config for a ClickOnce deployment

Tags: .net, clickonce

We have developed a .NET 4 client application (Windows Forms) to be used in an enterprise environment. The client is supposed to be published in many different flavors, which is causing us some headache. One of the requirements is that the client must be able to communicate with quite a few different application servers, via SOAP web-services. The application server (AS) publish identical WS-interfaces but the underlying server-system is different, typically one instance per customer served by our enterprise. Secondly, we have an internal Operations department that also must have access to all of these application servers in order to support our customers.

The network structure is such that internally the AS-servers are on the 10.0.0.0/8 network while all customers have public IP-addresses to access the application servers. Currently we access by IP but are migrating to use DNS names, although the DNS-name of the server will not be identical for internal and external (customer’s) access.

The result of this is that we have a lot of different configurations in app.config to manage since by default the WS-connection information is stored there. I have posted a related question previously ([The best way to manage multiple client endpoint configurations (IP-address etc) in app.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931359/the-best-way-to-manage-multiple-client-endpoint-configurations-ip-address-etc)) and it helped quite a bit but we still trying to improve the configuration management. As described in the referenced posting we now have the possibility to set up different configurations/builds for each endpoint connection similar to profiles if you are familiar with Maven (Java).

The problem is now that, since we’re using ClickOnce deploy and let the users install via a URL, we need to deploy a lot of different variants, i.e. for a single AS we need at least two deploys/builds, one with the public IP endpoint and one with the internal IP endpoint. Multiply this with a lot of AS-server it’s easy to see that it require us to juggle a lot of build configurations. Clearly there is room for improvement.

Some of the ideas and options we considered are:

- Skip endpoint configuration, at least the address part in app.config and have it soft-configured by the user in a Settings form. Our experience is that it’s not without problems either, typically it requires a bit of support for the end users and they easily get it wrong.
- Customized installer, research if there is any way the endpoint can be dynamically configured, e.g. since the client application will be deployed on the same server as which the web-services are published, can the installation somehow pick up the source URL and use that to locate the AS-server?

Any ideas on how to improve the deployment process and other related experiences are most welcome. I guess we’re not the first having this problem.

Also, we are willing to skip ClickOnce deploy if a superior method exists.

Regards, Ola

Answer (score 3):

First of all it is possible to customise your app.config and then custom publish it using mage.exe, i.e. you don't have to use Visual Studio to do the publishing. You mention you don't want to publish many different clients, but this knowledge may help with your thoughts about the process.

Secondly, I would advise that you publish a directory service. This is a web service (that is published to a pre determined location, which means you can bake the end point address into your application), you query it passing enough parameters to identify which user/client is calling, and it can return you the URI of the actual web service interface that you need to be calling. The directory service can determine where you are calling from (it can determine your IP) therefore it knows whether you are calling internally or externally, and based on that it can return the appropriate IP.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Your idea with the directory service is one that we have considered and it's still a candidate. Thanks again for the input.

Answer (score 2):

I really like slugster's idea of a directory service. Getting the client to ask which service to call keeps you flexible and will stop you having to redeploy the client if you change which service certain customers need to call into.

That said, you may still have complex configuration. Which comes back to customizing your app.config. For that you could use [ClickOnceMore](http://clickoncemore.net). Its a third party build tool (disclaimer: I built it) for building ClickOnce deployments outside of visual studio. And more importantly for you it has a macro system that allows you to set up multiple configurations. You can build it from the command line specifying which configuration you're building. Based on that configuration it can replace different values in your app.config or just select a different app.config file altogether. See [here](http://clickoncemore.net/documentation/browser.php?page=macros) for more details on the macro system.